# Application launch image on iPad mini issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, launching-application, ipad-mini

I have some UI bugs in launch image on iPad mini device. My application is for iPhone only, but anyway when you start it on iPad it has launch image too.

I have

```
Default-568h@2x.png for 4-inch retina display
Default@2x.png for 3.5-inch retina display
Default.png for non-retina display
```

What image will iPad mini use for launch icon.

Comment: if your application is only for iPhone then it is not require to set image for iPad/iPad mini

Comment: yes, but you should agree that anyway I can launch it on iPad and I will see launch image anyway. The question is what image do iPad mini require for launch image?

Comment: Aggree with Rauru Ferro, You should have a 1024 x 768 (Portrait) and 768 x 1024 (Landscaoe) png images for iPad mini launch screens, just create launch image for this size and put it in your sorce. thats it, it will work.

Comment: ok, suppose I have this images, where can I set them (my application is only for iPhone, it's not universal)

Comment: please see my below answer

Answer (score 1):

You Have to add two images for iPhone with below name it will automatically consider this as launch image.

```
Image Name : Default@2x~iphone.png  Size: 640*960
Image Name : Default~iphone.png     Size :320* 480
```

Add images with above name and above size, @2x is for iPad/iPad mini

Answer (score 0):

You should have a 1024 x 768 (Portrait) and 768 x 1024 (Landscaoe) png images for iPad mini launch screens.

Comment: ok, in this case where can I set them? My application is only for iPhone, so it's impossible to set iPad images

Comment: If you've set correctly your app project for iPhone (In Tab General in your project Target), Xcode won't ask for any iPad image. Check that you don't have set Universal App instead iPhone App.

Comment: yes, and I don't see settings for ipad, and it's ok, and that's why I don't understand your advice "You should have a 1024 x 768 (Portrait) and 768 x 1024 (Landscaoe)"

Comment: Could you put a screenshot of the general target screen? And of your project.plist file?